# Matlab (machine learning) - How to calculate binary scatter plot with straight line distinguishing these values?

Tags: matrices, functions, matlab, machine-learning

Maybe title sounds a bit confusing, so I'll try to explain it. Let say we have a some matrix 4x4 =

```
(0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 1
 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0)
```

So some function should check matrix values, and if it finds zero, it would assign let say `0` and if 1, it would assign `+`. So having such scatter plot where are two kinds of values is there some kind of function to calculate what should be the line between these two kinds of values, so it would show prediction depending on that line, like this: 
http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/images/scatter-ice-cream1a.gif,
but having two kinds of values (in image there is only one). And I suppose it would calculate line by some error if these two kinds of values would be mixed very much?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. I'm guessing you haven't tried logistic regression yet? Also, this has nothing to do with MATLAB.

Comment: you'll have better luck at CV.SE, but only after you refine your question.